# "Fall from" vs. "fall off"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> - She fell from the bike.
> - She fell off the bike.

Comment: If she was riding the bike she fell off it. If she was leaning it against the wall and climbing it to reach a can of paint in the garage, she fell from it.

Answer (score 2):

Which you should prefer depends on the particular circumstances, and what is being fallen from (or off).

You would usually fall *off* a bicycle, *off* the wagon or *off* the radar.

You might fall *off* or *from* the roof or the top of a mountain.

You would usually fall *from* a tenth-floor balcony, *from* grace, *from* a great height or *from* the top stair.

But both sentences are correct.

Comment: in general "fall off" implies a sense of movement or detachment from something while "fall from" is related to the location (physical or not - eg: grace).

Comment: @msam I agree. To fall off something implies you were on it. The relationship is one of juxtaposition, ie a continuum metaphor. To fall from something implies you were in the containment field it implies, ie a containment metaphor. See Lakoff's work on grounding metaphors.

Comment: So do you fall from a tree or off a tree?

Comment: @Peter: You fall ***out of*** a tree.

Answer (score -2):

when the process is reversible then use 'off' like 'He fell off the bicycle and got injured' but when the process is irreversible then use 'from' like 'He fell from the terrace and died.'

Comment: So you would say *he fell off the bicycle and was injured* but *he fell from the bicycle and died*? Why? Do you have any references for this distinction?

Comment: see bro if he dies by falling from the bicycle then it is obviously a non reversible process because he cannot get up now, but this will not be the case when  he gets injured as now he can get up so it is a temporary or reversible process, hope you understand now